# thread Safe Connection to MongoDb for just read data

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pymongo

i use `pymongo` `from pymongo import MongoClient`and it work very good but now i change my program to async and multi tread server and got eror like :

```
can't pickle_thread.lock objects
```

or

```
can not pickle local object MongoClient.__init__.<local>.target
```

i use only database For read from it and dont change any thing so there is no need to lock on Mongo db but `threding` and `queue` madule set look on that and get error ,

is there any way to create a thred safe connection to mongo Just for Read data(find , aggregate)

my server call 1 to 5 class dynamicly (whitch is multi thread) and all of them connect to DB

Comment: You try using the connection context manager.